# __Proto object in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

When considering this simple example

```
<script>

function test()
{
 this.x = 10;
}

var obj = new test();
</script>
```

I read in on one of the blogs that when we use a new keyword , a **proto** object would be created and **"this"** would be set to **proto** object.
So, when I just call `var obj = test();` , will the **"this"** be set to **proto** object or will the **proto** object not created at all in this scenario?
So, what would be the basic difference from a programmer's point of view between the two calling methods?

Comment: Without `new` keyword, you are just invoking test function and in that case, `obj` will be undefined as `test()` does not return any value...

Comment: There are a million questions here about the *new* operator and constructors called as functions. But maybe [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read in on one of the blogs that when we use a new keyword , a proto object would be created and "this" would be set to proto object.

If that's what it said, it was wrong.

If the *new* operator is used when calling a function, the function's *this* parameter is set to a new Object created as if by `new Object()`. This object has its internal `[[Prototype]]` set to the constructor's public *prototype* object.

It also causes the function to return this new object (and instance of the constructor) if no other object is returned by a return statement, so:

```
function test() {
  this.x = 10;
}
var obj = new test();
```

Creates a new object with a public *x* property with value `10` and internal `[[Prototoype]]` property that references *test.prototype*. A reference to this new object is assigned to *obj*.

> So, when I just call var obj = test(); , will the "this" be set to proto object or will the proto object not created at all in this scenario?

You mean like:

```
var obj = test();
```

In this case, *test* is called without setting its *this*, so it will default to the global object (or be undefined in strict mode), so that:

```
this.x = 10;
```

creates an *x* property of the global object (if it didn't already exist) and assigns it the value of `10`. This effectively creates a global variable, with subtle differences to one created using a variable declaration in the global execution context.

Comment: It would be nice if down voters said why the did so, then the answer might be improved.

Answer (score 4):

```
var obj = new test();
```

this would set x= 10 in the context of 'obj' only. That means after above statement if you do

```
console.log(obj.x); //output will be 10
console.log(x) //output will be error
```

Now, when you do:

```
var obj = test();
```

this would set x=10 in the execution context (global prototype). That means after above statement if you do:

```
console.log(obj.x); //output will be error
console.log(x) //output will be 10
```

Comment: "*this would set x=10 in the execution context (global prototype)*". What? The global execution context is an environment, it doesn't have a prototype, nor does the global object have a prototype (or internal `[[Prototype]]`).

Comment: @RobG Usually every object (except the ones derived from `null` (because `null` has no prototype)) has a prototype, no matter the object context. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262809/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-object-createnull-versus/32262852#32262852) post and [this](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/creating-objects-without-prototypes.html) article.

Comment: There is no "object context", nor any global prototype. Assigning to an undeclared, or otherwise "uncreated" variable, creates a property of the global object. There is no prototype involved.

Comment: For the sake of this question, when you do 'var obj = test();', it will attach 'x' property to 'window' object.

Answer (score 1):

The `new` statement creates a new instance (object) which basically inherits from the constructors `prototype`. However, the function's prototype (`__proto__` in most environments) has nothing to do with the instances' prototype. If not used as a constructor (i.e. without `new`), the function will use different object context, in this case the global one (in hosting environments like the web browsers, this would be `window`). From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain):

```
var o = new Object();

o.[[Prototype]] = Foo.prototype;
```

About the object context: [more](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md) details. About the prototype and functions: [more](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/) details.

**Update** In relation to the Rob's comment below: *context and scope are not the same. Every function invocation has both a scope and a context associated with it. Fundamentally, scope is function-based while context is object-based. In other words, scope pertains to the variable access of a function when it is invoked and is unique to each invocation. Context is always the value of the this keyword which is a reference to the object that “owns” the currently executing code.* (More details [here](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/).)

Comment: "*…the function will use different object context, in this case the global one…*" a function's execution context is lexical and invariable, the value of its *this* parameter is not (except for broad arrow functions).

Comment: @RobG What do you imply by your statement? _Inside a function, the value of `this` depends on how the function is called._ (from MDN). That was my point.

Comment: The phrase "object context" is confusing. Every execution context has a *this* parameter that references an object (or any value in strict mode). The value of *this* is usually set by how the function is called. The execution context is actually very closely related to scope, since it forms a kind of object with variables as properties that sits on the scope chain. I'm just commenting on the expression.

Comment: @RobG Again: see my update in the post, you seem to misuse the terms.