# TypeError: obj.hasOwnProperty is not a function when calling Graphql mutation

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js, node-soap

I get a strange error and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I wrote a graphql mutation to call an api:

```
domainStuff: async (parent, { command, params }, { models }) => {
  console.log("Params:", params);
  const result = await dd24Api(command, params);
  return result;
}
```

This it the function I call:

```
export default async (command, parameter) => {
  const args = _.merge({ params: parameter }, auth);
  // Eleminate copying mistakes
  console.log(typeof args);
  const properCommand = command + "Async";
  const result = await soap
    .createClientAsync(apiWSDL)
    .then(client => {
       return client[properCommand](args)
         .then(res => {
            console.log(res[command + "Result"]);
          return res[command + "Result"];
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      return err;
      });
     })
   .catch(err => console.log(err));

return result;
```

with this query variables:

```
{
"command": "CheckDomain",
"params": {"domain": "test.it"}
}
```

The console.log shows me that args is an object, but I get this error (from the first catch block):

```
TypeError: obj.hasOwnProperty is not a function
```

How can that be? After all I checked whether it is an object and it is. More strange, if I give a hardcoded object into the query, this for example:

```
domainStuff: async (parent, { command, params }, { models }) => {
  console.log("Params:", params);
  const result = await dd24Api(command, {domain: "test.com"});
  return result;
}
```

then it works perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong? Thx for any help in advance.

EDIT: I am using "graphql-server-express": "^0.8.0" and "graphql-tools": "^1.0.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after an extensive period of trial and error I was able to fix the problem. Changing the position of the objects I pass into the .merge function was the solution. The working code is:

```
  const args = _.merge(auth, { params: parameter });
```

Both are objects, but it seems like the object coming from the graphql variables did not have the required hasOwnProperty method. Simply speaking, instead of copying the "good object" (auth) into the bad one (parameter), I copy the bad one into the good one which has the needed function.

Hopefully this helps someone else who also experiences this error.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `graphql-js` there are a lot of places where new objects are created using `Object.create(null)` which is different from `{}` you can read an explanation about that here [Creating Js object with Object.create(null)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518328/creating-js-object-with-object-createnull)

But essentially an object created with `Object.create(null)` has no `hasOwnProperty` method

You can try it in node with

```
const obj1 = Object.create(null)
console.log(typeof obj1.hasOwnProperty)
// 'undefined'
const obj2 = {}
console.log(typeof obj2.hasOwnProperty)
// 'function'
```

Another method you can use for determining if an object has a key that will work on an object created with `Object.create(null)` is

```
function hasKey(obj, key) {
  return Object.keys(obj).indexOf(key) !== -1
}
```

Comment: I am using "graphql-server-express": "^0.8.0" and "graphql-tools": "^1.0.0". I just did a console.log with args.hasOwnProperty and I got back function. So it has this function. Nonetheless, thx for the explanation, definitively learned something here.

Comment: your error output says `obj.hasOwnProperty is not a function` not `args.hasOwnProperty` so i would look for a variable named `obj` and try the console.log on that

Comment: Fixed the error. Both were objects, but only one of them had the needed hasOwnProperty function. Seems like the data from the graphql variable overwrote the prototype. Had only to switch the sequence of the variables in the merge function. Thx for your input.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert it to a standard Object by:

```
data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Thanks. Writing to firestore from a graphql server and this was driving me crazy. A shorter alternative that seems to work is `const newData = {...incomingData}`

Comment: @tehfailsafe does not work for nested objects (creates shallow copy)