# group array and get count

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have array like this:

```
[
   "foo",
   "bar",
   "foo"
   "bar",
   "bar",
   "bar",
   "zoom"
]
```

I want to group it so I can get a count like so:

```
{
  "foo": 2,
  "bar": 4,
  "zoom": 1
}
```

is there a utility that can do this?

Comment: Yes, there's an "utility" for that, check out `Array.prototype.reduce`

Comment: `Object.assign({}, ...Array.from(new Set(array), key => ({[key]: array.filter(v => v === key).length})));` - inefficient, but meh

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use the function `Array.prototype.reduce`.

```js
let array = [   "foo",   "bar",   "foo",   "bar",   "bar",   "bar",   "zoom"],
    result = array.reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1, a), Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: o/w people think there is a variable called `b` somewhere

Comment: you should also mention the `comma operator` and how it works...many people won't understand the syntax if you don't explain it or link to it.

Comment: If anyone was confused by the section `, Object.create(null)` like I was, the comma uses the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) to return a null object. `Object.create(null)` is used rather than `{}` to create an [object with no prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518328/creating-js-object-with-object-createnull)

Comment: Please incorpate @bendataclear 's suggestion, it works and it is more clear.

      array.reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1, a), {})

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can `reduce()` your array to an object with the keys and the count, like this:

```js
const input = [
  "foo",
   "bar",
   "foo",
   "bar",
   "bar",
   "bar",
   "zoom"
];
const result = input.reduce((total, value) => {
     total[value] = (total[value] || 0) + 1;
     return total;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in a concise way via [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var arr = [ "foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "zoom" ] 

var result = arr.reduce((r,c) => (r[c] = (r[c] || 0) + 1, r), {})

console.log(result)
```

It gets really cute if you ware to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) and [_.countBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#countBy):

```js
var arr = [ "foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "zoom" ] 

var result = _.countBy(arr);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `reduce()` method which is avalible on the array object to achieve this grouping. So, something along the lines of this might achieve what you're after:

```js
    var input = [
       "foo",
       "bar",
       "foo",
       "bar",
       "bar",
       "bar",
       "zoom"
    ]
    
    // Iterate the input list and construct a grouping via a "reducer"
    var output = input.reduce(function(grouping, item) {
    
      // If the current list item does not yet exist in grouping, set 
      // it's initial count to 1
      if( grouping[item] === undefined ) {    
        grouping[item] = 1;
      }
      // If current list item does exist in grouping, increment the 
      // count
      else {
        grouping[item] ++;
      }
    
      return grouping;
    
    }, {})
    
    console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I guess with Array.prototype.reduce, it's just:

```
  const map = list.reduce((a, b) => {
            a[b] = a[b] || 0;
            return ++a[b], a;
          }, {});
```

wondering if there is less verbose way tho.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**: First, we [create object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) (a brand new empty object). Secondly using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) we first copy everything from the existing array and make a [new array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) out of it and use that to create a new [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) (the Set object lets you store **`unique`** values) and use that as the key, and finally we [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out our array (with a little help from the [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property) to see how many times a particular **`key`** occurs and set that to the object's **`value`**. And remember, since we used `Object.assign()` and put everything inside of it, so what gets returned is an object containing the result of everything that I tried to explain (to the best of my knowledge) above **:)** We also used the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) here which simply evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

```js
const arr = ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "zoom"];

const data = Object.assign({}, ...Array.from(new Set(arr), key => ({[key]: arr.filter(value => value === key).length})));

console.log(data);
```