# Nodejs console.log(response), show extra `[Object: null prototype]`

Tags: node.js, graphql

I follow the tutorial from GraphQl https://graphql.org/graphql-js/

```
var { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`);

// The root provides a resolver function for each API endpoint
var root = {
  hello: () => {
    return 'Hello world!';
  },
};

// Run the GraphQL query '{ hello }' and print out the response
graphql(schema, '{ hello }', root).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

When I run it, I expect to get

```
{ data: { hello: 'Hello world!' } }
```

However, instead I get

```
{ data: [Object: null prototype] { hello: 'Hello world!' } }
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

That's just how `console.log` shows objects that have `null` as their prototype instead of `Object.prototype`.

Compare

```
console.log({}) // {}
```

or

```
console.log(Object.create()) // {}
```

with

```
console.log(Object.create(null)) // [Object: null prototype] {}
```

`Object.create(null)` initializes an object that *doesn't inherit any properties or methods from `Object`*. There's a [few reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518328/creating-js-object-with-object-createnull) to do that.