# Why does reassigning __proto__ return different result?

Tags: javascript

```js
let p={};
p.__proto__=Array.prototype;
console.log(p.slice);   //ƒ slice() { [native code] }
```

However.. What's the difference?

```js
let o=Object.create(null);
o.__proto__=Array.prototype;
console.log(o.slice); //undefined.
```

Comment: This [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) might help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating JS object with Object.create(null)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518328/creating-js-object-with-object-createnull)

Comment: [*They are not equivalent. `{}.constructor.prototype == Object.prototype` while `Object.create(null)` doesn't inherit from anything and thus has no properties at all.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15518712/542251)

Comment: I know `Object.create(null)` got no prop. or prototype. But then I assigned `Array.prototype` to it. Should it inherit from Array?

Comment: Read the linked answer ***no properties at all***, not even `__proto__` look at the [screen shots in this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15518712/542251)

Comment: *But then I assigned Array.prototype to it. Should it inherit from Array* no it doesn't work like that. Your object has no intial link to object, all you've done is assign a property that happens to be called `__proto__` to the prototype of Array. This is not the same thing as updating the prototype of a prototype based object

Comment: Thank you Liam. I know now `o` doesn't even have [[prototype]] so it got no chain at all. Any object needs that chain (__proto__) to follow through something anyway. But here NO this chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__proto__` is not an ordinary property, it's an accessor, that is, some function ("setter") gets called when you assign anything to it and is responsible for setting the internal hidden `[[Prototype]]` property. This function is located in `Object.prototype`, so if your object is not connected to `Object.prototype`, the function is not invoked. As a result, `obj.__proto__ = xxx` simply creates a new property named `__proto__` in your object, which doesn't do anything.

In pseudocode:

```
Object.prototype = {
   get __proto__() {
       return this.[[Prototype]]
   }
   set __proto__(xxx) {
       this.[[Prototype]] = xxx
   }
}

myObject = {} // extends Object.prototype
myObject.__proto__ = xxx  // setter called!
myObject.[[Prototype]] is now xxx

myObject = Object.create(null) // extends null
myObject.__proto__ = xxx // no setter called 
myObject.[[Prototype]] is still null
```

Comment: _your object is not connected to Object.prototype_ cuz it doesn't have the accessor `__proto__` to call setter. Thx~