# Iterate Object and replace values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have this Object:

```
{
  "data": {
    "success": true,
    "historical": true,
    "date": "2022-01-01",
    "base": "MXN",
    "rates": {
      "COFFEE": 0.02158734144632395,
      "CORN": 0.008232645172711363,
      "COTTON": 0.04320921676820366,
      "SOYBEAN": 0.0036714622235960175,
      "SUGAR": 0.25680398615582695,
      "WHEAT": 0.00017592643558262669
    },
    "unit": "per bushel"
  }
}
```

And I want to iterate over "rates" to replace the values of each key with 1 / value
I tried with:  (prueba is the Object name)

```
Object.values(this.prueba.data.rates).forEach((val) => {
      console.log(val)
      val = 1 / val;
      console.log(val)
    })
```

But how to replace those values or how can I saved them in another array or Object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the change you made to `val` is only reflected within the scope of the callback.

You should instead loop through each property and set its value.

```js
const obj={data:{success:!0,historical:!0,date:"2022-01-01",base:"MXN",rates:{COFFEE:.02158734144632395,CORN:.008232645172711363,COTTON:.04320921676820366,SOYBEAN:.0036714622235960175,SUGAR:.25680398615582695,WHEAT:.00017592643558262669},unit:"per bushel"}};

let r = obj.data.rates;
Object.keys(r).forEach(e => r[e] = 1 / r[e])
console.log(obj)
```

If you're using Typescript it's necessary to declare the object like so:

```js
const obj: {[key: string]: any} = ...
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have an error Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ COFFEE: number; CORN: number; COTTON: number; SOYBEAN: number; SUGAR: number; WHEAT: number; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ COFFEE: number; CORN: number; COTTON: number; SOYBEAN: number; SUGAR: number; WHEAT: number; }'.ts(7053)  
I'm using typescript, so its setting e to a string type

Comment: Just solve it with the answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438198/typescript-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-expression-of-type-st  Thank you, could you just edit your answer with const obj: {[key: string]: any} ={} so if anyone with the problem can solve it, once again than you so much

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (or [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) and replace the value for each key.

```js
let obj={data:{success:!0,historical:!0,date:"2022-01-01",base:"MXN",rates:{COFFEE:.02158734144632395,CORN:.008232645172711363,COTTON:.04320921676820366,SOYBEAN:.0036714622235960175,SUGAR:.25680398615582695,WHEAT:.00017592643558262669},unit:"per bushel"}};
Object.entries(obj.data.rates).forEach(([k, v]) => obj.data.rates[k] = 1 / v);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you but I have the same error as using @Spectric answer:  
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ COFFEE: number; CORN: number; COTTON: number; SOYBEAN: number; SUGAR: number; WHEAT: number; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ COFFEE: number; CORN: number; COTTON: number; SOYBEAN: number; SUGAR: number; WHEAT: number; }'.ts(7053)

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be cleaner to write it explicitly using for loops:

```js
let obj = {} //original object stated in question
let obj2 = Object.create(null);//DON'T just use {}, see below
for(let productName in obj.data.rates){
   let inverse = 1/obj.data.rates[productName];
   //to edit the object directly
   obj.data.rates[productName] = inverse;
   //to add to another object
   obj2[productName] = inverse;
}
```

The difference between `{}` and `Object.create(null)` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518328/is-creating-js-object-with-object-createnull-the-same-as)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array#forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Code:

```js
const obj = {data:{success:0,historical:0,date:"2022-01-01",base:"MXN",rates:{COFFEE:.02158734144632395,CORN:.008232645172711363,COTTON:.04320921676820366,SOYBEAN:.0036714622235960175,SUGAR:.25680398615582695,WHEAT:.00017592643558262669},unit:"per bushel"}}

const replaceValue = ({ data: { rates: r }}) => 
  Object
    .entries(r)
    .forEach(([k, v]) => r[k] = 1 / v)

replaceValue(obj)

console.log(obj)
```